# boot - no LUKS password prompt

Tags: 14.04, boot, 16.04, luks

During boot, I am not asked for LUKS password, so boot fails. Same behavior with failsafe grub option, so no CLI password prompt either.

I have:

- initrd.img-3.13.0-39-generic
- initrd.img-3.13.0-40-generic
- initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic

but only initrd.img-3.13.0-39-generic works correctly and asks for cryptsetup password.

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS from Ubuntu 14.04, but I had this problem also with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This appears to be a bug. You can subscribe to status updates here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1359689

Comment: @ElderGeek I edited my question so it is clearer that I'm also missing CLI password prompt.  
In my case it is not bug 1359689.

Answer (score 1):

No luks password prompt - plymouth

With Ubuntu 17.10 in November 2017 the problem remains:

Bug 1359689 Ubuntu or Red Hat Bugzilla – Bug 1086972  are still valid. 
It is a Plymouth issue, not an issue of LUKS or NVIDIA or Linux-distro.

Issue: 
I have an encrypted non-root-partition (actually /home) and the whole lifecycle of booting, working, closing  works flawless. 
Boot and LUKS will handle the process based on crypttab and fstab, no entry in inittab. Follows the (correct) specs and works well.

Except the password request.

Plymouth swallows the password request.

Here we do NOT talk about the initram issue - this is a slightly different situation, same bug. So solutions for similar cases do not work here.

Reproducible 
you can try to guess when the request should be there, manually enter the matching password and the mounting goes on well.

Reproducible, 
when you prematurely press "enter" during(!) the checking step the displayed lines shift up (and display an empty line). 
The password request becomes visible in this empty line after finalised checking procedure. 
Could probably be circumvented by adding more newline characters, it seems.

So it is clearly a display issue caused by Plymouth.

The request for password is fired up correctly. 
It is just not visible to the user.

I do not have a NVIDIA in the machines I implemented it in. 
It's happening on laptop with Intel graphics as well as on a desktop with A10 APU graphics.

Graphics card does not matter at all.

How to get this Bug in Plymouth reported? 
I ask for your help to manage the endless bureaucracy to issue a bug report.

For sure it was reported plenty of times before and silently closed to avoid the hassle.

Can I reactivate an older bug for this Plymouth failure to cooperate with LUKS encryption??

Comment: Please share back if you figure this one out! I have the exact same issue (though I do actually have an nvidia card as well...)

Comment: Bug #1731769 reported (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1731769).

Comment: due to not-so-helpful comments it looked like someone found the solution. It was a solution for a different problem :-(  This means the bug is no longer taken serious and nothing will happen. Ubuntu 18 and Fedora 27 have exactly the same bug. Fedora is even worse since it hides the request for password even "better".   I give up and get used to the problem.....

Comment: Ubuntu 19 Disco still has the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/1256730 , but afaik I have correct fstab.
I created 2 files, run update-initramfs and I see password prompt again:

```
   $ cat /usr/share/initramfs-tools/conf-hooks.d/forcecryptsetup
   export CRYPTSETUP=y
   $ cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/cryptroot 
   CRYPTOPTS=target=sdc2_crypt,source=UUID=252ce099-c4e4-40f4-a832-6e20fea422af,lvm=vg
   $ update-initramfs -k all -c
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. However since the information you provided appears to be focused on your environment, would you be so kind as to [edit] your answer with further details to explain the choices that you made so that others with the same problem can benefit from your experience? I thank you and the community thanks you.

Comment: Hallo PeTer, hallo ElderGeek: HERE we do NOT talk about the initram issue - this is a slightly different situation. The initram issue is dealt with in other places. Please do not mix up one issue with a solution for a different issue. This does not help.

Answer (score 0):

@PeTer's solution was the only working solution for the same problem on my laptop. As a side note, in the latest cryptosetup/initramfs versions, `CRYPTSETUP` must be set to "y" in another file:

```
/etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a proper `/etc/crypttab` file. Also, remember to add your mountpoints to the `/etc/fstab`.

crypttab should contain something like this:

```
targetname physicalpartition none
```

For instance:

```
targetData /dev/sdb3 none
```

Where targetData is a name you create for the target that will be used by `/dev/mapper`.

Hope this helps... Good luck!